# Heat map on Gnuplot from data file

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I'm trying to generate a 2D heat map from this data file, I think the data is well organized as the following  :

```
0.0 40.0 778.78278125477152
0.0 50.0 821.24429287113696
0.0 60.0 857.79296488547618
0.0 70.0 890.06095542158732
0.0 80.0 919.06388700600121
0.0 90.0 945.48341255862601
0.0 100.0 969.80434954392581
0.0 110.0 992.37671186761020
0.0 120.0 1013.4707149747477

0.05 40.0 785.04864919102374
0.05 50.0 827.79091606458678
0.05 60.0 864.58789436029519
0.05 70.0 897.07701069047266
0.05 80.0 926.28235753807337
0.05 90.0 952.88921361293615
0.05 100.0 977.38381162397832
0.05 110.0 1000.1186956644323
0.05 120.0 1021.3657924885772

0.10 40.0 791.56219381880612
0.10 50.0 834.59605743738416
0.10 60.0 871.64993375468521
0.10 70.0 904.36959867719099
0.10 80.0 933.78659257178356
0.10 90.0 960.58894183366590
0.10 100.0 985.26431849394919
0.10 110.0 1008.1691538800941
0.10 120.0 1029.5762691876521

0.15 40.0 798.34195708520997
0.15 50.0 841.67845253218343
0.15 60.0 878.99959021841130
0.15 70.0 911.96216498184424
0.15 80.0 941.59880756758344
0.15 90.0 968.60362475969566
0.15 100.0 993.46813275542991
0.15 110.0 1016.5504255441598
0.15 120.0 1038.1240698190288

0.20 40.0 805.40633887246452
0.20 50.0 849.06078650575785
0.20 60.0 886.66143919098226
0.20 70.0 919.87513653318490
0.20 80.0 949.74270901298996
0.20 90.0 976.95976182084962
0.20 100.0 1002.0200216289010
0.20 110.0 1025.2865573011743
0.20 120.0 1047.0349932153122

0.25 40.0 812.77820696975073
0.25 50.0 856.76498891660458
0.25 60.0 894.65789851038267
0.25 70.0 928.13609087809073
0.25 80.0 958.24365100449450
0.25 90.0 985.68264624290816
0.25 100.0 1010.9500913222986
0.25 110.0 1034.4103129303267
0.25 120.0 1056.3393347758583

0.30 40.0 820.48464481223357
0.30 50.0 864.81798335532392
0.30 60.0 903.01887516609315
0.30 70.0 936.77239583815219
0.30 80.0 967.13114999006245
0.30 90.0 994.80346504788190
0.30 100.0 1020.2873912704987
0.30 110.0 1043.9504525864115
0.30 120.0 1066.0703849020231

0.35 40.0 828.55422268229802
0.35 50.0 873.24932742561214
0.35 60.0 911.77247403032084
0.35 70.0 945.81595169717775
0.35 80.0 976.43897273583991
0.35 90.0 1004.3562269840540
0.35 100.0 1030.0677813747072
0.35 110.0 1053.9436827572483
0.35 120.0 1076.2649157912790
```

i want something like this [image: heat map]

This is what I tried to make the heat map with the only contour line at 930.

My commands were the following:

```
unset surface
set dgrid3d 
set contour 
set cntrparam levels discrete 930
set table
set out "e-nb-hierro.out"
splot "mapa-estabilidad.dat"

´´´
And then, after getting out of gnuplot and opening it again, becasue otherwise didn't make the graph, I use this commands:

´´´
unset table
set term pngcairo enhanced dashed color size 35cm,30cm font 'Arial, 28'

set output "Estabilidad.png"
set pm3d explicit
set pm3d map
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
set palette model RGB  defined ( 1.4 'black', 1.7 'blue', 2.0 'red', 2.1 'yellow')

set xlabel "{/Symbol a} [MeV]"
set ylabel "{/:Italic Bag} [MeV/fm^3]"
set cblabel "{/:Italic {{/Symbol e}/n_B }}[MeV]"

set size square

set xrange [0.0:0.35]
set yrange [40:120]
set mxtics 2
set mytics 2

set xtics 10,15,100

splot "mapa-estabilidad.dat" u 1:2:3 w pm3d not, "e-nb-hierro.out" u 1:2:3 w l lt 8 lw 3 lc 'white' not
```

After this i get the following image :

[image]

As you can see, this isn't a good contour line (930) is just and horizontal line, not following the pattern like a curved line. And the other problem is that it doesn't label the x-axis.
Please help

Comment: You need to turn the table mode off before switching to the png terminal to make an image rather than a table: "unset table".

Comment: solved the problem for the contour line, i took out the set dgrid3d

Comment: solved the other problem, i had the tics away from the interval i needed

Comment: @martíncanullán good to hear that you solved your issue. I would encourage you to answer your own question with the solution which worked. Such that others can learn from it and this question doesn't stay unanswered. For your working solution, do you really still have to end gnuplot and start it again, as written in your script above? This would sound odd to me.